# Unable to add new key-value pair dynamically to a STATE JSON Array in React App

Tags: json, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to add a new key-value pair to the already loaded JSON Array. I am adding the new key-value pair to customize the header column cells in react bootstrap table but getting the below errors. Can any one please help?

[image]

'Columns' in the below state is where I wanted to add new key-value pair

```
state = {
        data: MYResult.Products || [],
        actualData: MYResult.Products || [],
        columns: MYResult.ParametricList_Attributes || [],
        isCompareClicked: false,
        isDisabled: true,
        selected: []
    };
```

This is how I am adding the key-value pair -

```
componentDidMount(){


        checkbox = (column, colIndex) => {
            return (
                <h5>{ column.text }<checkbox/></h5>
            );
        }
        console.log(this.state.columns) ;
        newColumn = this.state.columns.map((column) => {

            return {...column, headerFormatter: checkbox};
        });
        this.setState({columns: newColumn });
    }
```

Full code here  - https://codesandbox.io/s/o1r988qkz Please uncomment the componentDidMount() to see the issue

Comment: You have a typo in the map value, `dcolumn` instead of `column`, is that by mistake?

Comment: yes its a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's a typo in `dcolumn` and `column`.
And regarding the `not defined` error, you need to define it using `const`. Use like:

```
const checkbox = (column, colIndex) => {
      return (
        <h5>{column.text}<checkbox /></h5>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript variables need to be declared when they are used. Public class syntax can not be used everywhere. The error you're getting is self-evident - 'checkbox is not defined'.
Refer this on how to use it: https://tylermcginnis.com/javascript-private-and-public-class-fields/

I simply declared the undeclared variables in your example and the code worked.